# Worksheet_change not working with a formula and Worksheet_Calculate giving Compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a Graph change colour depending on a a specific value in a cell (Stage Gate 1-5). Here is my test code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then
 If Target.Value = "Stage Gate 5" Then
 Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
 Else
  MsgBox "error"
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

This works fine when the values are just typed into the cell. However if the value is derived from a formula it does not work. I have tried changing the worksheet_Change to worksheet_calculate but that just gives me [Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoVCP.jpg).

If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Range("M2").Value = "Stage Gate 5" Then
    Sheet15.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(167, 34, 110)
Else
    MsgBox "error"
End If

End Sub
```

It works even if value is derived from a formula.